# Lightning UI for appexchange apps

Tags: lightning, appexchange

We have a few apps in appexchange and with the new lightning UI, many users would probably start using the new lightning UI. In one Trialheads it says that your apps can apply lightning ready certification.

> AppExchange Apps with Custom Objects, Visualforce Pages, and More
>
> Many apps from the AppExchange feature customizations, including
>   custom objects, custom buttons, Visualforce pages, and more. As part
>   of the Lightning Experience rollout, partners are testing their apps
>   in the new experience and applying for a Lightning Ready
>   certification. Apps that are Lightning Ready will work in Lightning
>   Experience and offer a more consistent user experience with other
>   Lightning pages. If an app is supported in Lightning Experience, a
>   "Lightning Ready" sash appears on its AppExchange listing. If an app
>   isn’t supported in Lightning Experience, use it in Salesforce Classic
>   instead.

Is there any documentation on the criteria for lightning ready certification. Any guidelines on how to make your app both classic ready and lightning Ready? Or can an app be only lightning ready or salesforce Classic ready

Answer (score -1):

Quoting from the [Are You Ready for the New Lightning Experience?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/08/are-you-ready-for-the-new-lightning-experience.html)

Resources to Help Get Your App Lightning Ready

> Partner Community Page for All Things Lightning Experience Webinar
>   recording, Resources, FAQ, and more! p.force.com/lightningready
>
> Lightning Ready Certification for ISVs Chatter Group
>   https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009PYa
>
> Pre-Release Org Signup Here
>   https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter16-partner.jsp
>
> DECK: Lightning Ready – What is Lightning Ready? Dos & Don’ts,
>   everything you need know about getting your app Lightning Ready by
>   Dreamforce 2015. https://partners.salesforce.com/06930000005Pgaj
>
> DECK: Salesforce Lightning Design System Overview
>   https://partners.salesforce.com/06930000005Pgae
>
> Salesforce Lightning Design System – Login information will be
>   provided when you submit a case to enable the new Salesforce on your
>   GS0 org. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/
>
> DECK: Lightning Experience Partner Pre-release Enablement
>   https://partners.salesforce.com/06930000005Pgao
>
> Trailhead Trails on Lightning Experience
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead